# Implication of one to one exponential function

Tags: integration, derivatives

[image]

I'm confused at what this question is asking... when it says $b^x = b^y$, is it referring to the inverse of $b^x$? Thanks!

Comment: It is not referring to the inverse of $b^x$.  You have two expressions: $b^x$ and $b^y$.  They are equal to each other.  Therefore (by an argument that you are meant to provide, which involves the injectivity of the exponential function) $x=y$.  Then show the converse (though this is relatively straight-forward).

Comment: More generally, if $f$ is a function and is one-to-one, show that $f(x9=f(y)$ if and only if $x=y$. See if there is any explanation needed at all beyond writing down the definitions of "function" and "one-to-one".

Comment: Oh... by any chance would I have to suppose x = y, then $x^b = y^b \to blogx = blogy => x/y  = 1$. This shows it's x equal y because x/y = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

it seems that you have to prove that 
$$
e^x=e^y \quad \iff \quad x=y
$$

using only the fact that the function $f(x)=e^x$ is one-to-one, that is : for any $z$ in the range of the function, there is only one $x$ in the domain such that $z=f(x)$.

If so, the simpler way is by contraposition: suppose that $e^x=e^y=z$ and $x \ne y$, so .....

Comment: Oh. Could you check if my answer in the comment section is correct? It's quite similar to yours.

Comment: You don't nedd logarithms !  Simply use the definition  of a one-to-one function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused.. wouldn't the contraposition be x != y <=> e^x != e^y? And I've been thinking for a while... how does this conclude anything?!